# EF - Many To Many INSERT

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many

I have to insert record in one table and in the many-to-many table with two FK.

I have: Products 1<=>n Products_Supplier n<=>1 Supplier

Products: ID, Name, Code
Products_Supplier: ID, ID_Products, ID_Supplier, Availability, Active, Price, Brand
Supplier: ID, Name, Site

Supplier list is already with data, no need add anything there.

I have to add data in Product and Product_Supplier, where Product_Supplier needs to have the ID of the product added and also the data I ve to add: Availability, active and price. Product_Supplier needs also the id for supplier. Here is what i did so far, but it gives Validation error:

```
                    Products_Supplier.ID_Supplier= supplier.Id;

                    Products_Supplier.Products.Name= record.productsVM.Name;  //insert product name
                    Products_Supplier.Availability = record.productsVM.Availability; //here shud insert availability of the product inserted before
                    Products_Supplier.Active = record.productsVM.Active;
                    Products_Supplier.Brand = record.productsVM.Brand;
                   
                    dbContext.Products_Supplier.Add(Products_SupplierObj);
                    dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

if any doubt, ask them.

Answer (score 0):

If you have followed the [entity framework conventions](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx) you'll have classes like this

```
class Product
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    ... // other properties

    // Every Product is supplied by zero or more Suppliers (many-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Supplier> Suppliers {get; set;}
}

class Supplier
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    ... // other properties

    // Every Supplier supplies zero or more Products (many-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products{get; set;}
}
```

> In entity framework the columns of the tables are represented by non-virtual properties. The virtual properties represent the relations between the tables: one-to-many, many-to-many, ...

Because you use `virtual ICollection<...>` on both sides of the relation, entity framework knows that you designed a many-to-many relation and will create the junction table for you, even though you didn't mention it.

Now apparently you have an existing Supplier, and and existing Product, and you want the supplier to supply this Product: simply add it to the `virtual ICollection<...>`

```
Supplier supplier = dbContext.Suppliers.Where(...).FirstOrDefault();
Product product = dbContext.Products.Where(...).FirstOrDefault();

// The Supplier will supply this product.
supplier.Products.Add(product);

// or the Product will be supplier by the supplier:
product.Suppliers.Add(supplier);
```

It might be that property Products is null. In that case:

```
supplier.Products = new Product[] {product};
```

If you want to add a new Product and let supplier supply it:

```
supplier.Products.Add(new Product
{
    Name = ...,
    ... // other Product properties
});
```

Don't fill primary keys nor foreign keys. They will be filled by the database when you SaveChanges

Comment: I have database first, so it is a bit different from that. supplier.Products doesn't work, I am forced to use supplier.Product_Supplier